# how to show data from checboxes according to their clicking order

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show data from checkboxes according to the order they've been clicked. i'm using php and mysql for this purpose. i've been stuck here for days. This code just selects the check boxes and show them line by line i.e from first till the last. I want to set priority of the data inserted in checkboxes.

```
require_once 'DB.class.php';

$db = new DB();

$con = $db->connect();

$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($

    con, $_POST['pid']);`enter code here`

    $checkboxl = $_POST['chkl'];

$title='';

if ($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit'){


    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkboxl);$i++){
        $temp = $checkboxl[$i] ;

   $title .= $temp . ' || ';

    }



$InsQuery = "UPDATE contents SET Title='$title' WHERE PID='$pid' ";
$query = $db->query($InsQuery);

echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('Title has been inserted!');window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";

}else if($_POST['submit'] == 'Show')
    {
     for($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkboxl);$i++){
        $temp = $checkboxl[$i] ;

   $title .= $temp . ' || ';

    }
    $script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('Title: $title');window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";

    echo $script;

}else{
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.alert('ERROR!');window.location.href = 'index.php';
</script>";
```

Comment: Can you show the code where have you been stuck for days.?

Comment: Dont post your code as a comment. Instead of that edit your question and add code in that

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It may work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
   <form name="myform" id="myform" method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" id="firstcheck" class="mycheck" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="secondcheck" class="mycheck" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="thirdcheck" class="mycheck" />
   <input type="checkbox" id="fourthcheck" class="mycheck" />
   <input type="hidden" id="hiddenarray" name="hiddenarray" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        var checkarray = Array();
        $('.mycheck').click(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            if($(this).attr('checked')){
                checkarray.push(id);    
            }else{
                checkarray.splice($.inArray(id,checkarray),1);
            } 
        });
        $('#myform').submit(function() {
            $('#hiddenarray').val(JSON.stringify(checkarray));
            return true;    
        });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Then here is the php code to display the data of check boxes in the order they checked.

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['hiddenarray'])){
        $array = json_decode($_POST['hiddenarray']);
        print_r($array);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't do it with php alone. PHP is a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using PHP alone.

You can achieve it with Javascript, by keeping track of the order and then somehow sending it back, probably using a hidden `input` field. You should learn a little Javascript, give it your best try, and then come back if you get stuck again.